# Does Silex support custom user roles

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, silex

I been playing with Silex for the past few weeks and I'm about to start a major stepping stone. Authentication has always caused me some trouble.

I been looking at documentations / examples for the past few days and I can't seem to find any answers to what I am seeking.

I can tell Silex supports ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER but I don't see any ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN. Is it possible to modify the user provider/interface to handle this extra role and if so where could I find the proper documentation for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that roles are "mostly" arbitrary in that you can define whatever role you want (like: `ROLE_AWESOME_USER‍‍‍`, etc...) but `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_ADMIN` seem to be referenced in Symfony tests as well as the core `UserInterface.php` class.

The [Silex documentation covering security](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html) should have most of what you need. There is also a pretty good example of a firewall setup in [this so question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299064/silex-security-provider/23324471#23324471)

Here is my default firewall config at current:

```
'security.firewalls' => array(
    'main' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/',
        'anonymous' => true,
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/login',
            'check_path' => '/login_check',
            'username_parameter' => 'form[username]',
            'password_parameter' => 'form[password]',
            'form_login' => array(
                'csrf_provider' => 'form.csrf_provider',
            ),
        ),
        'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/logout'),
        'users' => array(
            'username' => array(
                '%security.role%',
                '%security.password%',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'security.role_hierarchy' => array(
    'ROLE_USER' => array(),
    'ROLE_ADMIN' => array('ROLE_USER'),
    'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' => array('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH'),
),
'security.access_rules' => array(
    array('^/user', 'ROLE_USER'),
    array('^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
    array('^/root', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'),
),
```

Comment: Where are you getting `'role_heirarchy'` from?

Comment: It's in the [SecurityServiceProvider](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php#L74)